# sql query is slow

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a phpmyadmin database with 1 000 000 record i need to search in. Every week there are 500 000 records added.

so, this is what I need:

```
location_id value   date        time        name                lat     lng
3            234    2011-11-18  19:50:00    Amerongen beneden   5.40453 51.97486
4            594    2011-11-18  19:50:00    Amerongen boven     5.41194 51.97507
```

I do this with this query:

```
SELECT location_id, value, date, time, locations.name, locations.lat, locations.lng FROM
(
SELECT location_id, value, date, time from `measurements` 
LEFT JOIN units ON (units.id = measurements.unit_id)
WHERE units.name='Waterhoogte'
ORDER BY measurements.date DESC, measurements.time DESC
) as last_record
LEFT JOIN locations on (locations.id = location_id)
GROUP BY location_id
```

which takes 30 seconds. How can I improve this? This is my structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `locations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lat` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `lng` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `owner_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=244 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `measurements`  
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `measurements` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `location_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `unit_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=676801 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `owner`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `owner` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `units`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `units` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `unit_short` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `owner_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=44 ;
```

What is the limit what phpmyadmin can handle?

Comment: I wanted to clarify that its not a phpmyadmin limitation. It is how fast mySql is able to run the query.

Comment: note: phpmyadmin is NOT a database. it's a PHP-based **INTERFACE** to a mysql database server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an index on units.name specifically is a good start.
You should also really rethink the amount of data you are pulling back.
Is someone really going to sift through that many records.  Change your query to limit the number of records and think of a UI interface that involves a paging mechanism.

Comment: I replaced WHERE units.name='Waterhoogte' with: WHERE units.id=4, which brings it down to 2 seconds. Are there any other ways to rewrite this query in a better way?

Comment: Do you have an index on this field?  You may want to have an index on location.id as well.  Ultimately there is little more you can do to make your query go "Faster".  It's more of an issue of how many records you are bringing back to the client.  Limit that and write some nice UI that triggers more records when needed.  Bringing back that many records is just a no no.  When you do a google search and it brings back 40 pages of results, in most cases you only care about the first 2 pages, if even the second page.

Comment: okey, thanks ya all! : Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 30 total, Query took 1.4580 sec), i can live with this

Comment: @Melvin - to me that is fairly quickly.

Answer (score 2):

you need to put an index or unique index on units.name.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following indexes:

A composite index (a covering index) on unit.name and unit.id.
A composite index of measurements.date and measurements.time.
An index on location.id

Answer (score 0):

You should try creating an index on units.name as a first step. But understand that there is a tradeoff with an index - read operations will be faster, but it can slow down write operations. If you're concerned about that, or if you're affected by slow writes, then you may want to try creating the index on a smaller number of characters in units.name.

For instance, to declare an index on the first 12 characters of units.name, you'd declare the following:

CREATE INDEX first_twelve ON units (name(12));

Again, this may not be necessary if you don't notice any ill effects from just throwing an index on, but it's something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT measurements.location_id, measurements.value, measurements.date, measurements.time, locations.name, locations.lat, locations.lng
FROM measurements
LEFT JOIN units ON units.id = measurements.unit_id
LEFT JOIN locations ON locations.id = measurements.location_id
WHERE units.id = 4
GROUP BY measurements.location_id
ORDER BY measurements.date DESC, measurements.time DESC
```

Comment: thanks, it is faster but show the records from "measurements" by ASC, i want the lastest record. The order by need to happen before the group by. I cant figure out how this works. This query i had first actually.

Comment: @Melvin would probably be faster to have a subquery in your where clause. `date = select max date`. then you can get rid of your grouping and order by. would also be faster to have your date and time in one datetime field, but that's another story.